# Is it possible through SQL to correct a dataset by inserting adjusted lines?

Tags: sql, dataset

I'm running into a problem with our exchange rate dataset. This dataset saves every exchange rate like this (for example) :

Valid from: 01-01-2021
Valid to: 01-01-2021
Exchange rate: 0.9

Normally the valid from and valid to date are the same. But sometimes, due to an error, the exchange rate couldn't be saved for one or more days and then the dataset shows it like:

Valid from: 01-01-2021
Valid to: 05-01-2021
Exchange rate 0.9

For my data analysis I calculate based upon the relationship between valid from and for example the invoice date. But now, for all invoices that lay between 01-01-2021 - 05-01-2021 there is no relationship and therefore my calculations aren't correct. Is there a way through SQL that would do the following?

If valid from and valid to date aren't the same, insert a new line and copy the last exchange rate from the past for the missing dates? Or is there another way to solve this?

Many thanks in advance!

Gr. Diana

Comment: Do you want to OUTER JOIN a calendar table?

Comment: I think that might be the only way right? Can I create a calendar table within SQL?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. Often very useful.

Comment: But how will I make sure then, that the dates in the datetable refer to the value of a previous date if the specific date isn't available in the exchange rate table? And also, but maybe this is not the right place to ask this question, how do I outer join on a calendar table if that table isn't in the datawarehouse but in an external excel-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be doing this because you're making up data, which lowers the quality of your dataset. I think it would be better to take these situations into account in your query.

But if I had to I would do it like this and just run the query until there're no rows being affected anymore:

```
insert into exchange_rates (valid_from, valid_to, exchange_rate)
select 
    valid_from, 
    valid_from valid_to_new, 
    (
        select top 1 exchange_rate 
        from exchange_rates previous 
        where previous.valid_to <= invalid.valid_from
        order by previous.valid_to desc
    )
from exchange_rates invalid
where valid_from != valid_to;

update exchange_rates 
    set valid_from = dateadd(day, 1, valid_from)
where valid_from != valid_to;
```